# Android : nesting of horizontal and vertical list view like in google map

Tags: android, list, view

How can I achieve the interface of google map that has both horizontal and vertical list view? I have no clue how to nest things as well as remember the position of the horizontal scroll in each item

Screenshot attached 
[image: google map interface]

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with imageviews in scrollview and horizental scrol view like i did

```
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_weight=".20"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Vehicle documents"
        android:textColor="@color/emphasis"
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/com_gol_underline"/>
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:id="@+id/imageViewDocument1"
                android:background="@drawable/com_gol_box"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:id="@+id/imageViewDocument2"
                android:background="@drawable/com_gol_box"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:id="@+id/imageViewDocument3"

                android:background="@drawable/com_gol_box"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Vehicale images"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:textColor="@color/emphasis"
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/com_gol_underline"/>
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewVehicleImage1"
            android:background="@drawable/com_gol_box"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewVehicleImage2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@drawable/com_gol_box"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewVehicleImage3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@drawable/com_gol_box"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonSubmit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/com_gol_yellow_button"
        android:text="Submit Documents"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight=".10"/>
   </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: What if the number of vertical categories and horizontal elements is not pre determined?

Comment: Give your horzontalScrollView an id and access it programmatically, we can add views programmtically.

Comment: Ok so if I have many, if there some recycling? Would performance be impacted?

Comment: android:id="@+id/hLayout"
mLayout=(ViewGroup)rootView.findViewById(R.id.hLayout);
mLayout.addView(View child);

Comment: Well, I think you should try and test. We use to see performance when we have alternatives. Do you have any sir?